# Which word do I use? Are or Is?

Tags: word-choice

Which is correct?

Spelling and grammar on facebook is something else.

Spelling and grammar on facebook are something else.

Comment: The first seems to be increasingly common, but the second is correct.

Comment: Either is correct, depending on the meaning intended.

Comment: Spelling and grammar, together, are something else.

Comment: Spelling and grammar on Facebook is (implied as phenomenon) something else. Spelling and grammar on Facebook are (both things explicitly) are something else.

Answer (score -1):

*are* is the plural form of the verb, so when you talk about "Spelling and grammar" (i.e. two things), *are* is the correct word to use.